# Route to external site via Istio Virtual Service

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm working on a side project to learn Istio in my spare time, part of which is getting my hands dirty with Istio routing.

I'm trying to setup a Virtual Service such that any traffic on "/" gets routed to google.com. I can get Virtual Services to work with any in-cluster pods/services, but I can't seem to configure Istio to route to anything outside the cluster.

Any guidance would be much appreciated, cheers

Answer (score 1):

You have [to create a Service Entry](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#configuring-istio-external-services) for google.com and then create a Virtual Service, referencing google.com in the same way as in-mesh services. Note the issue of the protocols - do you want to access google.com by HTTP or HTTPS? You may want to let Istio [perform TLS origination](https://istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-egress/egress-tls-origination/) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a service entry for google.com. Refer [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/) documentation overall, and precisely [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#configuring-the-external-services).